# Две строки с "одинаковыми" символами эмодзи, почему-то не равны друг другу js

Tags: javascript, emoji

Есть такой код:

```js
const emo = ['⭐', '⭐️'];
console.log(emo[0] === emo[1]) // false
console.log(emo[0].length) // 1
console.log(emo[1].length) // 2
```

Кто сильно шарит в символах эмодзи, объясните пожалуйста, как это работает. Почему два "одинаковых" эмодзи не равны друг другу, и почему у них разная длина?

Comment: [What does u'\ufe0f' in an emoji mean? Is it the same if I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100329/what-does-u-ufe0f-in-an-emoji-mean-is-it-the-same-if-i-delete-it)

Comment: `'⭐️'.charCodeAt(1).toString(16) // fe0f`

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/itelma/articles/549366/

Comment: Дело тут даже не в символах, а в том, что в Вашем коде присутствовал лишний байт, который ничего не выводит, но из-за него длина получается на единицу больше и соответственно false. (Я исправил.) Это можно исследовать в шестнадцатеричном редакторе.

Comment: @Опан не надо это исправлять, потому что вы своей правкой убили смысл вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, что в Вашем коде второй ячейки массива присутствуют 3 байта - EF B8 8F, которые ничего не выводят на страницу. Так как длина увеличивается только на единицу, то скорее всего эти байты соответствуют какому-то символу эмодзи, который не поддерживается ОС. Попробуйте просмотреть этот код на других устройствах с другими ОС или в других браузерах.